# C style Lexer issue when tokenizing multi line comments

Tags: c

Ive been assigned to write a "C-Style" lexer for one of my CS courses. Currentlly we are only tokenizing string, comments and classiying everything else as tokens.

This installment we were tasked with implementing the function to tokenize comments delimited by /* and ending in */

All is well exept for the fact that during a multi line comment my code will print an extra line. like so

Comment: /* Multi

Comment:       line

Comment:          comment*/

when it should look more like

Comment: /* Multi
Comment:       line
Comment:          comment*/

anyway ive been stuck on this for too long. Im thinking its because of my end pointer being in the wrong spot but ive had no luck in debugging

heres my tokenize code

```
void tokenize(char* line, int length, int* inComment) {
   int start = 0;
   int end = 0;
   while (end < length) {
      if((line[end] == '/' && line[end+1] == '*') || *inComment == 1){
         if(*inComment != 1){
            *inComment = 1;
         }
         while(end < length){
            if(line[end] == '*' && line[end + 1] == '/'){
               end+=2;
               *inComment = 0;
               break;
            }
            else{
               end++;
            }
         }
         lex(line, start, end, 3);
         start = end;
     }
....
```

and heres my lex() code incase its helpful

```
void lex(char *line, int start, int end, int tokenType){
   char token[MAXTOKEN];
   while(start < end && isspace(line[start]) && tokenType != 3){
      start++;
   }
   if(start >= end){
      return;
   }
   strncpy(token, &line[start], end-start);
   token[end-start] = '\0';
   switch(tokenType){
      case 0:
      printf("Token: %s\n", token);
      break;
      case 1:
      printf("String: %s\n", token);
      break;
      case 2:
      printf("Char: %s\n", token);
      break;
      case 3:
      printf("Comment: %s\n", token);
      break;
   }

}
```

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED

I have tried editing the end pointer

Comment: "_ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED_" Are you stripping the `'\n'` off each line as each is loaded?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] complete with input and output examples.